# How to migrate Login Service from Ruby to ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, cookies

I am planning to migrate some part of my website from Ruby to React while others still need to be supported on Ruby as Front-end.
But the main issue I am facing is concerned with Login Service.

In case of Ruby, after Login,cookie that gets generated is defined as

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_my_session'
```

So, even if I create a new login page using ReactJS ,I need to create a similar cookie(as I need to support some old pages on Ruby that use this cookie for authorization) after successful authentication.
So is there any way to create this 'my_session' from ReactJS ?Or How I can decode 'my_session' cookie?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to read and write that cookie without rails, but the implementation is specific to the version of rails you're using and the way your rails application is configured. But more importantly, that cookie is likely marked HTTP-only and in that case it isn't possible to read or write it from a client side app (not in React or anything other client side library). The login scenario is typically something you do on the server side and the server (Rails in your case), uses HTTP headers to read and write that session cookie. Set-Cookie to write to your user agent via HTTP response and Cookie when reading from the request sent by your user agent.